# Find fields name in given template in DocuSign

Tags: php, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am trying to find the field (data label) name of the given template ID using php sdk, Do Any ideas or suggestions to find the data label name passing the template ID in PHP(laravel) rest API
Also your suggestions are welcome

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client/blob/master/src/Api/TemplatesApi.php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this method

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-php-client/blob/f056cf2b7ebe671b95421e335de24b78d80a259a/src/Api/TemplatesApi.php#L3881

Something like this:

```
$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\TemplatesApi\GetOptions();
$options->set_include("tabs");
$templates_api->get($account_id, $template_id, options)
```

The endpoint is documented here - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/templates/templates/get/